# viewing database images the right way up - php

Tags: php, image, landscape-portrait

I have a basic upload + Gallery view for pictures. thanks to a recent question i asked i have arranged them by date. However i am now having trouble displaying the pictures the right way up i.e. landscape/portrait.

PHP code:

```
<?php
$sql="SELECT * FROM chiseldonuploads ORDER BY id DESC";
$result_set=mysql_query($sql);
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result_set))
{
?>
<img class="photos" src="uploads/<?php echo $row['file'] ?>">
<?php
}
?>  
</div>
```

Current View of the Images
[image: Current View of the Images]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you expecting PHP to understand which side is up? I doubt that PHP rotates the images automatically and gives you the wrong rotation.

Comment: I wasn't expecting it no, i was hoping there is some code where it would landscape or portrait the picture.

Comment: What do you mean? So, all of the images are in landscape now (W > H) and one of them is correctly rotated. What do you hope the code to do?

Comment: so i took one in landscape and the others in portrait. However the current view has them all in landscape

Comment: Do they show the same on your computer? Did you process the images when they were uploaded?

Comment: I am using mobile to upload the pictures. after setting up a preview of the image before upload -- they seem to be saving as landscape

Comment: I have just tested an upload via computer making sure the img was portrait and it has managed to upload it as potrait. There seems to be an issue when taking the photo on mobile it doesnt save as portrait/landscape depending on what is being taken